# Can we fix this typo in the suggested edits queue?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, design

I recently gained access to the suggested edits queue and noticed a typo, shown in bold:

> - Approve edits you know are correct
> - Improve Edit ***the edit*** by making additional corrections
> - Reject and Edit the original post and provide a completely new edit
> - Reject those you know are wrong
> - Skip if you are not sure and want to go to the next suggested edit

[image]

All of the other sentences read normally to emphasize when the buttons on the suggested edits queue should be used, except the "Improve Edit" line.

Just wanted to point this out in hopes that it can be corrected.

**Suggestion:**

Update the line to be the following so that it matches the theme of starting the sentence with the label of the buttons in the queue:

> Improve Edit by making additional corrections

Cheers.

Comment: perhaps this better tagged as [meta-tag:design] than bug?  Just my opinion.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, perhaps, I really wasn't sure what to classify it as so I tagged it as a bug because that is the practice my organization classifies typos as because it still requires a "fix" to the application.

Comment: Why not both? ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus, works by me. :)

Comment: What has been seen cannot be unseen and now this will bother the the hell out of me.

Comment: @SlyRaskal Ok.  Do you have any suggestions for a better wording?  If so, you could also consider changing your post from just a discussion to an actual feature-request.

Comment: Proposal: *Improve the Edit by making additional corrections* No reason why we can't use "the" right?

Comment: @ryanyuyu, thank you for that point, I most certainly should have done that.  I've updated the post to include a suggestion.

Comment: @Compass, the text for the other lines are written such that the starting of the line is the same as the labels for the buttons on the queue, so I would suggest "Improve Edit by making additional corrections" so that they continue to match.

Comment: @Compass: Ironically, I saw this when I got access to the queue and was intensely annoyed, but forgot about it until I saw this question. So apparently I *did* unsee it?

Comment: @NathanTuggy did you notice I used two "the"s in my original sentence?

Comment: @Compass: *What sorcery is this? **How did you slip that past me?***

Comment: Currently the text updated as: **Improve Edit** when you can make additional improvements to the post